# Why Star Trek vessels have "USS" designation, when they're "produced" by Federation?

Tags: star-trek, federation

Following [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75795/7885), Why Star Trek vessels have "USS" (United States Ship) designation, when they're produced, founded, ordered and managed by Federation of Planets?

Shouldn't their designation be something like "FPS" (Federation of Planets Ship) or just "FS"?

Is there any "United States" (or just "Earth") in 24th century in Star Trek franchise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within the Star Trek universe, the USS doesn't stand for United States Ship, it stands for United Star Ship (or United Space Ship in the earliest episodes).

> **TRELANE:** *You must excuse my whimsical way of fetching you here, but when I saw you passing by I simply could not resist.*
>
> **KIRK:** *I'm Captain James Kirk of the **United Star Ship Enterprise.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Squire of Gothos](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/16.htm)</sup></sub>

---

> **OLD MAN:** *They're men. They're humans.*
>
> **PIKE:** *Captain Christopher Pike, **United Space Ship** Enterprise.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Menagerie](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/16.htm)</sup></sub>

---

It's also named as the United Star Ship (the S.S. Yorktown) in the original [studio pitch](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/1_Original_Series/Star_Trek_Pitch.pdf) by Gene Roddenberry

> You are therefore posted, effective immediately, to command the following:
>
> **The S.S Yorktown.**
>
> **Cruiser Class** — Gross 190,000 tons
> **Crew Complement** — 203 persons
> **Drive —** space-warp. (maximum velocity .73 of one light-year per hour)
> **Range** — 15 years at galaxy patrol speeds
> **Registry** -- Earth, **United Space Ship**

---

In answer to your supplementary questions, no, the United States no longer exists in the 22nd Century. It's part of a single global government known as [United Earth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/United_Earth).

Comment: While in-universe correct it's still worth mentioning that (out-of-universe) the naming was picked for a reason - make the audience (primarily US) identify themselfes with the ship and the crew (give them the "they are our boys/girls"-feeling).

Comment: @Ghanima - I don't think you're incorrect, but I've not seen any interviews/statements that confirm this thinking.

Comment: A marvelous answer with a lot of examples. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It stands for United Star Ship in-universe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was faster than Richard's one, but Richard has provided a lot of cites and more details, so I'm picking his answer and only voting-up yours.